# jquery で一致するすべての要素を取得するには？

Tags: jquery

jquery で要素の指定はできるのですが１つの要素しか取得できないんです
HTMLは以下のようになっているのですが

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="ABC">
            <tr>
                <td class="rank">1</td>
                <td class="name">taro</td>
                <td class="country">japan</td>
                <td class="score">100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rank">2</td>
                <td class="name">bob</td>
                <td class="country">america</td>
                <td class="score">300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rank">3</td>
                <td class="name">magna</td>
                <td class="country">france</td>
                <td class="score">150</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

jquery で

`$("table tbody.ABC tr td.name").html()`

のように指定しても

`taro`

の１つしか取得できないんです

`taro`
`bob`
`magna`

の３つを取得する方法はありますか？

Comment: 値の取りだしはどうやってますか？ `.each`を使ってそれぞれの要素を処理することになるかと思いますけど。

Comment: すみません追記しました。

`$("table tbody.ABC tr td.name").html()`
のようにやっています

Answer (score 0, accepted):

選択された要素をそれぞれ処理するには例えば`each`を使います。

```
$("table tbody.ABC tr td.name").each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());//それぞれの要素に.html()する（alertは実際の処理が不明なため）
});
```